# Formula to look up cell in a list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to write a simple formula that looks up a cell's value in a list. If value is in list then return "4512 Marked Up". If not, return blank.

For example, IF(A1=VENDORS,"4512 Marked Up","")
Where VENDORS is the list
But I can't get it to work properly.
Thanks

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,VENDORS,0)),"4512 Marked Up","")`

Comment: That did it! I was missing the "0". Thanks!